# Confusing property assignment in python _init_ function

Tags: python

The following code snippet is from [SQLAlchemy source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py):

```
class EngineStrategy(object):
    """An adaptor that processes input arguments and produces an Engine.
    Provides a ``create`` method that receives input arguments and
    produces an instance of base.Engine or a subclass.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        strategies[self.name] = self
```

how does the last statement work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EngineStrategy` is a kind of *abstract* class. If you try to search the usage of this class you will only find inheritance from it.

So `self.name` goes actually from `cls.name`(class variable), like in the following [`PlainEngineStrategy`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py#L197-L201):

> ```
> class PlainEngineStrategy(DefaultEngineStrategy):
>     """Strategy for configuring a regular Engine."""
>
>     name = 'plain'
>     engine_cls = base.Engine
> ```

This allows to store all *strategies* in `strategies` dict with structure: `{'stategy_name': strategy_class}`

<sub>*Related to `sqlalchemy` note*: mirror of official repo is now at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy</sub>

Comment: Thanks! But `EngineStrategy` inherits from `object` not `PlainEngineStrategy` and `object` has no class variable named `name`?

Comment: You right, but think of `EngineStrategy` as base class, that you only inherit and never initialize by it&#39;s own. And if you inherit from it, initialize without providing class variable `name` will get you an `AttributeError`. So providing class variable `name` is obligatory if you inherit from `EngineStrategy` and have a plan to create it's instances.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort vishes but I'm not indeed convinced. It's still so absurd to me that `name` in `EngineStrategy` is instance variable but class variable in `PlainEngineStrategy`, how can the latter inherit from another?

Comment: @mzoz All class variables can be access via instances, and instances will store values from class until instance-level override happens. As you can see after each child declaration instance is initialized (https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py), to populate the `strategies` dict.

Comment: I played around with some code and it all makes sense now, much appreciated vishes!